# Decoding stripslashes gzinflate base64

Tags: php, base64, decode, stripslashes

I have a problem with a wordpress theme. I am not a programmer to write a theme from scratch so i was looking for one free. When I installed the theme on the local server to make change the look, error. I get an error on the functions.php and on that line is this code:

```
<?php eval(stripslashes(gzinflate(base64_decode("VZBNS8QwEIbvC/0PcyikhbJ611rY9QPZxZOKSKCUyYSETZOSpB4U/7uztCLCHGbeZ767m+sO9Owx2+ABDeGpNzQoilX9VWwAoHStFE+7l9cd7t/swd0e3h+OUlwtULfKRj+MVPX9/ePxru/rrRQXS4vtZKa/TNXqMJGvSt1IEaWoV4CtjpzOumq0dZTsJ3FQr1yjC+ksqFWwuko5TiFVJTalq9v2cl0VgNAEkOLZ2ATZ0EjATiRHQyIFs+elAHlath8EGMYx+ATOInmkBgbnOPCnBNafy0GHkLkimTA7xX3GgYH1ecD8exeAsrS438WG7f8PmRSbjp/8Aw==")))); ?>
```

I've spent couple of hours trying to make it work by decoding it but fail after fail. I get more junk... I respect the work of others but is really frustrating when someone release something for free but then you realize is not actually "free". Also i would like to to change the design on the footer and add some more stuff, not to delete the credits but can't because of the same issue. I would appreciate if someone can help me with this. Here is the header and footer also:

header

```
<?php eval(stripslashes(gzinflate(base64_decode("VZDLSsUwEIb3hb7DLAppoRzFjQuNBUVBcCXiKlDKZGLGkyYlSV0ovrs5tCLCLGb+b+7DzfUAZvWYOXhAS3gcTQiZYtt91RUANE4qcbfm1/f14vKW38wzK3G1ISM1Rz/N1I7jw+PT/Th2ByXOtgaHxS5/mVqasJBvG9MrEZXodoDSRJp00XVv2FHiTypBt3ODLqSToHeBTZtyXEJqG+wb10l5vi8KQGgDKPFiOUG2NBMUJ5KjKZGG1WuKgGVa5g8CDPMcfALHSB6ph8m5EvhjAvanctjOgGTD6nTpM08FsM8T5t+7ADTT5n7XVbH/Hyykroby4h8=")))); ?>
```

footer

```
<?php eval(stripslashes(gzinflate(base64_decode("dVLBSgMxED0r+A9DC7aCutVju27BigfRi+1FWCjZ3dkmmGZCkrrdvzfZbSxYmkuSN/PeTN5knqWV+AFRPeWDmsihyQfZ1eVFh5aSWfsXkFi7Pnhdkm5nkFrNFFjXSvRJJUky0+FkMpn5rHSuuYZC0kaomsb5SLEt5qObGcyzNAnEDF7Qio3CCooWUgbcYO11uHN6miQLg80bFfa+pK3XC1cI9zRhGQgFvpxkBRnmBClohOOnGu9YMIUWV+wbWcPag1aEIeJB8/aU/kU7s+BGWCeYWmpWYmwmgvCxs6I8Q39G617J4P6TCnLxIQGFDoYeD+xgeOIdP+O8ERt+sP5Y5cRhY+3jemfkwWWf/7lcBnXPiUPyhlVo7sIopw96D5akqGBYdsvPLYoPObKq+wsr0v86jPvx1LfS6HXf7rirH8IFVW134G4r/Z/4BQ==")))); ?>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please *always, always* quote the exact error message that you are getting. It is horribly annoying to have to guess the basics of an issue

Comment: Re "not really free": Can you post the theme link? This kind of stuff seems to be a relatively common measure to protect a copyright notice or link to the theme's creator, which seems somewhat fair if it's mentioned beforehand.

Comment: it seems there is no error but just `decode wordpress footer` question again. they're infinite

Comment: @user the best way to fix these issues might be to contact the Author themselves.

Comment: "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at E:\xamp\xampp\htdocs\piano\wp-content\themes\metube\functions.php(41) : eval()'d code:14) in E:\xamp\xampp\htdocs\piano\wp-content\themes\metube\functions.php on line 220" The 220 line is where the base64 code start...

Comment: i asked the programmer about this issue, and he said he doesn't have a problem on the local server. I tried xamp and wamp, same problem. Third, i don't want to remove the credits from footer, i respect his work but i just want to be able to put a better design on and the code don't let you to do that.

Comment: the theme link: http://www.wordpressthemesbook.com/metube-youtube-clone/

Answer (score 1):

Change eval -> echo to view source

Answer (score 0):

"That line":

```
?><? function check_header(){
   $l='NBUVBcCXiKlDKZGL';
   $f=dirname(__FILE__).'/header.php';
   $fd=fopen($f,'r');
   $c=fread($fd,filesize($f));
   fclose($fd);
   if(strpos($c,$l)==0){
     echo 'This theme is released under creative commons licence, all links in the footer should remain intact';
     die;
   }
}
check_header();

?><?
```

Header:

```
?><? function check_footer(){
   $l='CutVju27BigfRi';
   $f=dirname(__FILE__).'/footer.php';
   $fd=fopen($f,'r');
   $c=fread($fd,filesize($f));
   fclose($fd);
   if(strpos($c,$l)==0){
     echo 'This theme is released under creative commons licence, all links in the footer should remain intact';
     die;
   }
}
check_footer();

?><?
```

Footer:

```
?><div id="footer">
    <div class="footerleft">
    &copy; <span style="color:#000;"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></span> Designed by <a href="http://CrewJobs.com">Crew Jobs</a> in collaboration with <a href="http://LebaneseTakeaway.com">Lebanese Takeaway</a>, <a href="http://YourChristianSpace.com">Christian Music</a>, <a href="http://BestForexRobots.com">Best Forex Robots</a>
    </div>
    <div class="footerright">
    <a href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>">RSS</a><a style="border-left:1px solid #cccccc;" href="#header">Top</a>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html><?
```

edit: copied the wrong line

Comment: Lebanese Takeaway? Best Forex Robot? WTF kind of a template is this? O_o

Comment: Pekka, the theme developer wants to build a network of links to his own sites for SEO purposes (i.e., blackhat SEO or at least rather grey).

Answer (score 0):

Note that all Wordpress themes always must be released under the GPL license because Wordpress itself is under the GPL (version 2).

Here are a couple of FAQ questions where the Free Software Foundation answers such questions:

http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0-faq.html#GPLAndPlugins

http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0-faq.html#IfLibraryIsGPL

http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0-faq.html#MereAggregation

http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0-faq.html#GPLInProprietarySystem

This means that any Wordpress theme author who release code under any other license than GPL is infringing the copyrights of the Wordpress developers.

Unfortunately there is nothing you can do about that, but the WP developers themselves will have to sue the theme developer. This is the saddest part about the GPL, that you as a user cannot enforce it :-/

Comment: Myth not correct. The GNU GPL (as it is actually called) is only enforceable upon "linking" the code, which is generally disputed for scripting language code. Furthermore the WorsePress templates don't reuse code, but just call the API. No derived works. On the upside, you as user could indeed enforce the license *in some jurisdictions* - if there was a valid breach.

Comment: mario, the templates is so tightly coupled with the Wordpress core that they are in fact an aggregated work, at least if you can believe the FSF's FAQ (and they should now!). From the first FAQ link: "If the program dynamically links plug-ins, and they make function calls to each other and share data structures, we believe they form a single program". I agree with you on the scripting disputes though.

Answer (score 0):

Using `eval` is a common form of code obfuscation (this particular code uses the PHP `gzinflate` function to unzip itself), but it is easily defeated. It is possible to replace `eval` with `print` to determine what is being executed. As a first step, I've done this to [the header](http://www.ideone.com/nnCAq) and [the footer](http://www.ideone.com/9oXmt).

The header checks `footer.php` to ensure that it was not changed. It reads the entire file into memory (`fread(...);`) and then checks for a specific part of the gzip-compressed data (`if(strpos($c,$l)==0)`). If it is not present in the file, then the `die` command is used to close the WordPress software. In exactly the same way, the theme [checks the header](http://www.ideone.com/Ng40g). All this, however, can be easily defeated once the weak obfuscation is broken.

The footer is not very special except that it is a) obfuscated like the theme and header files; and b) includes hyperlinks to several other web sites. The creator's motive is probably to boost the search engine ranking of those sites (search engines rank sites higher if they have more inbound links).

To conclude all this,

- Code obfuscation using `eval` is used to obscure the meaning of the code.
- Files check each other for integrity, totally dependent on the strength of obfuscation.
- This theme seems to be primarily intended for boosting the search engine rankings of the sites linked to in the footer.